# Powershell Write Bitlocker status to text file

Tags: shell, encryption, text, cmd, powershell-3.0

I am trying to write the bitlocker status to a text file via powershell by invoking a cmd shell but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Here is what i have tried so far

```
    #doesn't work
    cmd /c manage-bde.txt>c:\bitlockerstatus.txt


    # makes an empty file
    $oProcess = Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList "manage-bde>c:\bitlockerstatus.txt" -wait -NoNewWindow -PassThru
    $oProcess.HasExited
    $oProcess.ExitCode

   #doesn't work
   [Diagnostics.Process]::Start("cmd.exe","/c manage-bde>c:\bitlockerstatus.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you call the exe directly from powershell using the `&` operator ?

```
 & manage-bde.exe -status > c:\temp\bl.txt
```